# Batch: Looping through folders and subfolders and get them into a script

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg

I want to convert `.flac` files from `X:\Music\flac\flacfolder\name.flac` to `X:\Music\mp3\flacfolder\name.mp3` using `ffmpeg`, but I couldn't find how to loop through while passing the directory to a different command and manipulating it.

Comment: Things are easier if you switch to PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, to process files recursively, I would suggest to use the [`for /R` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html). However, in this situation, since I guess you want to copy the directory hierarchy from the source to the target folder, I do not use it, because it resolves to absolute paths only. Instead I use [`xcopy /L`](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html), which does not copy anything (due to `/L`), but lists all applicable items as paths relative to the source folder; then I wrap around a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to read the list of relative paths and to resolve them related to the target folder; in the loop body finally, the `ffmpeg` needs to be placed (define the options to your needs and remove the preceding upper-case `ECHO` after having tested; the `ffmpeg` tool does not receive any relative paths but absolute ones only for both input and output files):

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=X:\Music\flac\flacfolder" & rem // (absolute source path)
set "_TARGET=X:\Music\mp3\flacfolder"  & rem // (absolute target path)
set "_PATTERN=*.flac" & rem // (pure file pattern for input files)
set "_FILEEXT=.mp3"   & rem // (pure file extension of output files)

pushd "%_TARGET%" || exit /B 1
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
    cd /D "%_SOURCE%" ^&^& ^(rem/ list but do not copy: ^
        ^& xcopy /L /S /Y /I ".\%_PATTERN%" "%_TARGET%" ^
        ^| find ".\" ^& rem/ remove summary line;
    ^)
') do (
    2> nul mkdir "%%~dpF."
    rem // Set up the correct `ffmpeg` command line here:
    ECHO ffmpeg -i "%_SOURCE%\%%~F" "%%~dpnF%_FILEEXT%"
)
popd

endlocal
exit /B
```

---

If you want the destination files in a flat folder structure instead, a `for /R` loop workes fine:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=X:\Music\flac\flacfolder" & rem // (absolute source path)
set "_TARGET=X:\Music\mp3\flacfolder"  & rem // (absolute target path)
set "_PATTERN=*.flac" & rem // (pure file pattern for input files)
set "_FILEEXT=.mp3"   & rem // (pure file extension of output files)

for /R "%_SOURCE%" %%F in ("%_PATTERN%") do (
    rem // Set up the correct `ffmpeg` command line here:
    ECHO ffmpeg -i "%_SOURCE%\%%~F" "%_TARGET%\%%~nF%_FILEEXT%"
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Looks like it's trying to search for the files in a .\file directory so it doesn't find them, for example: `.\Braid\08 Tell It By Heart.flac`
Instead of `E:\Music\Loseless Game Soundtracks\Braid\08 Tell It By Heart.flac`, but it copies the directories perfectly. 
Also, it tries to convert .bat, .log and .png files, but I think ffmpeg would just ignore them anyway so it's OK.

Comment: So when you define `_SOURCE` to be `E:\Music\Loseless Game Soundtracks`, the file `.\Braid\08 *.flac` is going to be found by the script. I do not know `ffmpeg`, so I am not sure whether it accepts relative paths like that, and I also do not know whether `\ ` is the correct path separator for this tool (perhaps it might expect `\\` or `/`), so when the script finds the paths; ffmpeg` might still fail to find them. Nevertheless, I corrected the file pattern from `*.*` to `*.flac` meanwhile to no longer match all file types...

Comment: Is there a way to make it a non-relative path?

Comment: Thanks for all the help, this works flawlessly.
If you can, please edit the main comment to reflect these changes to make it easier on future users that want to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have an example I used in the past. I tried adding your structure to it.

```
@echo off
cd X:\Music\flac\flacfolder

for /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%i IN ('dir /s /b ^| findstr .flac') do (
  call :process_code "%%i"
)

goto end


:process_code
echo Running conversion for %1
:: Run your process here

goto :eof

:end

echo done!
```

I hope this helps

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with filenames that include spaces.

Comment: @arielbeje Use `"%%i"` to take care of spaces.

Comment: @DavidPostill It instantly crashes that way.

Comment: I updated the answer to support spaces as suggested by @DavidPostill and I tested my solution with spaces. It worked.

Comment: Instead of `findstr .flac` let me recommend to use `findstr /I /L /E ".flac"`; the `tokens=1` is not needed /but does not harm though); instead of `"%%I"` use `"%%~I"`, and instead of `%1` use `"%~1"`; and add the `/D` switch to `cd`...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set FLAC_FOLDER=c:\temp\flacfolder
set MP3_ROOT_FOLDER=c:\temp\mp3folder
echo Processing folder [%FLAC_FOLDER%]...
for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir "%FLAC_FOLDER%\*.flac" /a-d /b') do call :PROCESS_FLAC_FILE "%FLAC_FOLDER%" "%%F"
goto END

:PROCESS_FLAC_FILE
set PFF_FOLDER=%1
set PFF_FILE=%2
set PFF_FOLDER=%PFF_FOLDER:"=%
set PFF_FILE=%PFF_FILE:"=%
for /f %%I in ("%PFF_FILE%") do set PFF_MP3_FILE=%%~nI.mp3
echo Processing FLAC file [%PFF_FILE%] in folder [%PFF_FOLDER%]; output file is [%PFF_MP3_FILE%]...

REM Now call ffmpeg using the approriate variables.  Enclose the variables in double-quotes, e.g.:
REM (note, I don't know the syntax for ffmpeg, so I'm making this up as an example)

ffmpeg.exe -source "%PFF_FOLDER%\%PFF_FILE%" -target "%MP3_ROOT_FOLDER%\%PFF_MP3_FILE%"

goto END

:END
```

Comment: This script repeats the same file a couple of times and only outputs two files. I think I set ffmpeg correctly:
`ffmpeg -i "%PFF_FOLDER%\%PFF_FILE%" -ab 320k -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 -n "%MP3_ROOT_FOLDER%\%PFF_MP3_FILE%"`